# how to create Enum in jenkinsfile and access its values?

Tags: groovy, enums, jenkins-pipeline

I need assistance. I need to create an Enum in jenkinsfile for our deployment environments. Each environment has specific configuration.

Please advise how can I create Enum in jenkinsfile and access the specific values. It should be like

```
Enum ENV {

 dev ('d-val1', 'd-val2'), 
 Int ('i-val1', 'i-val2') 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In plain groovy you do:

```
enum ENV {   

  Dev ('d-val1', 'd-val2'), Int ('i-val1', 'i-val2')  

  final String a1, a2
  
  ENV( String a1, String a2 ){
    this.a1 = a1
    this.a2 = a2
  }

  List<String> getValue(){ [ a1, a2 ] }
}

assert '[d-val1, d-val2]' == ENV.Dev.value.toString()
```